Two parallel lines in a parabola with a ratio of 1/3
Today I came up with a simple property for the parabola and I want to know if this ratio is known or not.

Being given a parabola, and two of its tangents in points $M$ and $N$, a parallelogram is constructed by taking parallels to the tangents at points $M$ and $N$ ; the new lines intersect the parabola in points $P$ and $Q$ ; parallel line segments $MN:PQ$ are in the ratio $\frac{1}{3}$
Of course, it is known that the two lines are parallel through the Pappus hexagonal theorem, but I would like to know if this ratio is already known, so I hope to mention a reference in the answers.
I think the property is known because of its simplicity, but I'm still not sure.
Relevant proofs or theorems are also welcome in the answers.

I believe it is due to the fact that OP is not a native English speaker.

I've never seen this relation before, but the proof is not difficult.
Let $_1$, $_2$, $_3$, $_4$ be the projections of the endpoints of chords $$ and $$ on the directrix, taken from left to right (see figure below).
By the properties of chords parallel to a tangent, we have that $M$ is the midpoint of $A_1B_2$ and $N$ is the midpoint of $A_2B_1$.
Hence $X_2$ is the midpoint of $_1_3$ and $_3$ is the midpoint of $_2_4$.
From that, $A_1A_2=3B_1B_2$ immediately follows.


Just to be clear, "properties of chords parallel to a tangent" means that MX2 and NX3 are perpendicular to the directrix, and pass through B1 and B2, respectively?

@chepner Parallel chords of a parabola have their midpoints aligned on a line parallel to the axis, and the tangent at the point where this line cuts the parabola is also parallel to the chords. See here for a proof.
